# How to use autocomplete on search bar on Ionic 4?

Tags: autocomplete, ionic4, searchbar

I'm looking for some example but cannot see anyone googling it, just what i want is to hardcode 2 or 3 words, thank you so much. Do i have to look for on ionic 3? or in angular2 better?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In your html file:

```html
     <ion-searchbar type="text" debounce="500" (ionChange)="getItems($event)"></ion-searchbar>
     <ion-list *ngIf="isItemAvailable">
         <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">{{ item }}</ion-item>
     </ion-list>
```

in your ts file:

```js
     // Declare the variable (in this case and initialize it with false)
     isItemAvailable = false;
     items = [];

     initializeItems(){
         this.items = ["Ram","gopi", "dravid"];
     }

     getItems(ev: any) {
         // Reset items back to all of the items
         this.initializeItems();

         // set val to the value of the searchbar
         const val = ev.target.value;

         // if the value is an empty string don't filter the items
         if (val && val.trim() !== '') {
             this.isItemAvailable = true;
             this.items = this.items.filter((item) => {
                 return (item.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
             })
         } else {
             this.isItemAvailable = false;
         }
     }
```

Comment: This stuff is from Ionic 4 or Angular? Dont know why this: "initializeItems()"

Comment: I'm looking for autocomplete at time im typing, that's what i asked, could you explain me if its angular or ionic? Also dont want to show the list of the cities at the beginning, just if contains what im typing

Comment: Please you would be so kind if you set also to click the item of the list to set the value on the searchbar

Answer (score 12):

Mohan Gopi's answer is complete, but in order to make use of the `debounce` attribute, you have to use the `ionChange` event instead of the `ionInput` event.

```html
<ion-searchbar type="text" debounce="500" (ionChange)="getItems($event)"></ion-searchbar>
...
...
```

That way the event will trigger after the user stops typing (after 500 milliseconds have passed since his last key press), instead of whenever a key is pressed.

Comment: this is correct. Make sure to use ionChange instead of ionInput. OR it won't work.

Answer (score 9):

Just wanted to share something I tried myself. I have implemented the autocomplete from Angulars material design (https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview)
But it did not look exactly as the rest of the ionic input components. I also tried the ion-searchbar but I did not like the search input, I wanted a normal ion-input So I did this:

html:

```
<ion-list>
 <ion-item>
  <ion-label position="floating">Supplier*</ion-label>
  <ion-input (ionChange)="onSearchChange($event)" [(ngModel)]="supplier"></ion-input>                        
 </ion-item>
 <ion-item *ngIf="resultsAvailable">
   <ion-list style="width: 100%; max-height: 200px; overflow-y: scroll;">
    <ion-item *ngFor="let result of results" (click)="supplierSelected(result)" button>
     <ion-label>{{result}}</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
   </ion-list>
  </ion-item>
 </ion-list>
```

in component.ts:

```
resultsAvailable: boolean = false;
results: string[] = [];
ignoreNextChange: boolean = false;

onSearchChange(event: any) {
    const substring = event.target.value;
    if (this.ignoreNextChange) {
        this.ignoreNextChange = false;
        return;
    }

    this.dataService.getStrings(substring).subscribe((result) => {
        this.results = result;
        if (this.results.length > 0) {
            this.resultsAvailable = true;               
        } else {
            this.resultsAvailable = false;
        }
    });
}

supplierSelected(selected: string) :void {
    this.supplier = selected;
    this.results = [];
    this.resultsAvailable = false;
    this.ignoreNextChange = true;
}
```

Granted the question was about ion-searchbar but maybe somebody out there also wants to use a normal ion-input like me. There is no clear icon but I can live with that, or just add one next to the ion-input. Could be that there is a way to turn the ion-searchbar into a normal ion-input style? Can't find it though in the docs.