# Creating ionic searchable select option in ionic 4 framework

Tags: ionic-framework, select, searchable

I want to implement searchable select in my ionic application to display countries and cities. i am new to the ionic framework can anyone help please.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54998476/how-to-use-autocomplete-on-search-bar-on-ionic-4 I hope it helps